# show gif loader when image is uploading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form where I am uploading files (images) through browse button.
I want to show a loader when a user clicks on upload button once he browse any image from his/her system.

I have no clue how can I make it work.
Here is my code.

```
<div style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5em;">
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="flUpload" id="lblInstructions"><span class="QLabel" id="lblInstruction">Click the first button below to find your file. After selecting the file, click <b>Upload</b>.</span></label></p>
            <input type="file" id="flUpload" name="flUpload">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnFileStub" name="hdnFileStub">
            <input type="hidden" id="HdnFileName" name="HdnFileName">
            <input type="hidden" value="4e7263a4-472b-4ad8-9e9e-79612053a13a" id="hdnQuestionStub" name="hdnQuestionStub">
            <p><span style="padding: 2 0; color: Red" id="ErrMessage"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center">
            <input type="submit" class="srFormButton" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" name="btnUpload">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: You should submit your form using `ajax`. Show loader on `ajax start` and remove on `ajax stop`.

Comment: @Azim you cant submit a file input with ajax.

Comment: It is possible. See my answer. @ardabeyazoglu

Answer (score 2):

Wrap you inputs with a `form` and then do like following. Hope this will help you.

**CSS**

```
.loader {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #fcfcfc url("http://www.mvgen.com/loader.gif") no-repeat scroll center center / 120px 120px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var formData = new FormData(this);

   if ($('.loader').length > 0) {
      $('body').append('<div class="loader"></div>'); //add loader if not exist
   } else {
      $('.loader').show(); // show loader
   }

   $.ajax({
       url: "/Home/Upload", //your url here
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processType: false,
       success: function(data) {
            $('.loader').hide(); //hide loader
            console.log(data);
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes. Basically, this should work:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" target="uploadFrame" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
   <input type="file" name="img">
   <input type="submit" value="upload">
   <div id="preloader" style="display:none;">Uploading...</div>
</form>
<iframe name="uploadFrame" id="uploadFrame" style="width:0;height:0;margin:0;visibility:hidden;position:absolute;"></iframe>

<script>
    function submitForm(){
        var preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
        preloader.style.display = "block";

        var iframe = document.getElementById("uploadFrame");
        iframe.onload = function(){
            // hide the preloader on complete
            preloader.style.display = "none";
        };

        return true;
    }
</script>
```